# Is SignalR Good option for Fixed interval Data Push Scenario for Larger Datasets?

Tags: load, signalr, push, environment, disconnect

I have created an SignalR application (IIS Hosted) sending data to set of SignalR groups.
noticed that clients stopped responding after some reconnects(100-150). Where as Server state is healthy, and unaware of Disconnected clients. This made me ask whether SignalR is a trusted/appropriate approach to be used for scenarios where data(250 KB approx) is pushed to 500 Groups at fixed interval, Each Group has unique data payload, and total connected clients subscribed to those groups can be 1000-1500.

Testing Environment:
Win7 100 SignalR Clients.
Win7 SignalR Server hosted on IIS.
Total number of Clients connected to system are 1000.
Total groups managed are 500.

Comment: How long is the interval you are sending data at? Do you send a unique data payload to all 500 groups during each interval? Why are the clients reconnecting 100-150 times? When the clients become non-responsive, do they enter the disconnected state?

Comment: Interval is 2000 MS, No, at each interval data is updating, and each group is associated with a Unique data set and updates to that data set is pushed to users connected to that group. No the clients doesn't gets disconnected state, when i set Disconnect timeout to 1-5 then it frequently gets disconnected and both server and client gracefully ends connection.

Comment: 1000 clients * 250 KB / 2s ≈ 1 gigabit. Just out of curiosity, is this the rate you are able to send at from the server before the clients stop responding? Also for how long are the clients unresponsive? After being unresponsive for a long time what state are they in, e.g. connected, reconnecting, disconnected?

Comment: No, payload size per client not more than 1 Kb. Total size of Data kept at SignalR is 250Kb, out of which it selects data which falls in say "Group A" and 4 clients are subscribed to That "Group A". so Kb data will be sent to those 4 clients. Lastly there is a problem with Long polling in SignalR, it doesn't behave as per stated in SignalR lifetime events as per configured timeouts.